# Symfony4 - accessing sevices.yaml from controller

Tags: php, service, symfony4

I am starting a symfony4 project, and I learned the "parameters.yaml" is now "sevice.yaml".

I setted some variables inside like:

```
parameters:
    smugmug.oauth_token: 'XXX'
    smugmug.oauth_token_secret: 'XXX'
```

And i try to access it from my controller like:

```
    dump($this->container->get('smugmug.oauth_token'));
```

But I have an error...

How does this new way of storing global variables is working?

Comment: `$container->getParameter('smugmug.oauth_token')`; Read [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html)

Comment: I have a "Notice: Undefined variable: container" when I try this (been to this page but I don't understand that container thing..)

Comment: In a controller is enough `$this->getParameter('smugmug.oauth_token')`
Have you extended the "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller" class?

Comment: I have this error: `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParameter" of class "App\Controller\ArticleController"`. (`$this->get('smugmug.oauth_token')` doesn't work either)

Comment: @AntoineNedelec 
I hope you found meanwhile a solution :D 
If not see my answer bellow in the thread ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to extend the Controller class

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function controlAction()
    {
        // ...
        dump($this->container->getParameter('smugmug.oauth_token'));
        // Or this solution
        dump($this->getParameter('smugmug.oauth_token'));
        // ...
        // return a response
    }
}
```

Comment: DAMN ! I was extending "AbstractController".. Changing that to "Controller" solved that thing :). Thanks a lot, I need to be more attentive !

Comment: Not working anymore as "Controller" is deprecated and you have to use "AbstractController" :(

Answer (score 9):

Now, as Controller is deprecated and you have to use AbstractController, you need also a dependency injection for the service parameter:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class MyStuffController extends  AbstractController  {

    private $params;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }
}
```

Then you can get your parameters like this:

```
$this->params->get( "app.your_stuff" );
```